# Weird behaviour of Modpoll while reading Holding registers

Tags: modbus, modbus-tcp

I use the Modpoll Modbus client utility for testing.

The command (I)

> .\modpoll -1 -t 4:hex -r 40072 -c 2 IP address

gives the following result (hex value for 2 consecutive holding registers):

> [40072]: 0x404F
>
> [40073]: 0x5C28

According to documentation, these two registers contains an IEEE 754 big-endian encoded single-precision float number. The corresponding value is around 3.24 (decoded with a IEEE 754 utility program).

I want to use Modpoll to directly read the IEEE 754 encoded 32 bit float. I get a similar result if and only if I enter the following command (II):

> .\modpoll -1 -t 4:float -r 40071 -c 1
>
> 3.203139

The value is not exactly the same because I read a current which varies over time.

If I enter:

> .\modpoll -1 -t 4:float -r 40072 -c 1

I get a totally different value.

Any idea how the very same value seems to be once in registers 40072 and 40073 (I) and in registers 40071 and 40072 ?